# Array list application to add cities

Tags: c#

Im writing a simple program to add different cities in array list and i'm stuck on the part where i need to add the specific city on the next line of the list,i would appreciate some help.

```
List<string> Cities;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Cities = new List<string>();
    }

    private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        for(int i =0;i < Cities.Count; i++)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(Cities[i]);
            listBox1.Items.Add(txtBoxEnterCity.Text);
        }


    }
```

Comment: Looking at your code, your `Cities` never even gets populated. So naturally, the loop in `ButtonAdd_Click` will not work, as the count will always be 0. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Welcome to SO - it's not clear what your program is meant to be doing - have you debugged your code to see what's wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding your input city from `txtBoxEnterCity.Text` to your list of `Cities` before looping through the cities. Then your count will not be 0 and you will still have it added to the list for the next time you add another city. Hopefully this is clear:

```
private void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Add new city to list
    Cities.Add(txtBoxEnterCity.Text);

    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    for(int i=0; i < Cities.Count; i++)
    {
        // Add each city to the ListBox
        listBox1.Items.Add(Cities[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you,very much that is what i was looking for now i can continue forward.